# magento: join product with attribute value

Tags: sql, magento, collections, product

I'm trying to list some of my product from a php script and I need to get some attributes's value. For exemple I'm trying something like this::

```
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1);
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('computer_type')
   ->joinAttribute('computer_type_value', 'eav/entity_attribute_option', "computer_type", null, 'left', 0)
```

`"computer_type"` from product collection store an id which is found in `option_id` field of the `eav_attribute_option_value` table:

```
 +----------+-----------+----------+--------+
 | value_id | option_id | store_id |  value |
 +----------+-----------+----------+--------+
 |     3738 |        14 |        0 | server |
 +----------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

I would like to join this table with my collection's result in order to have the value "server" displayed instead of the id "3738" but the way I'm doing it is not working and despite all my search.

I didn't find how to achieve that in only one query. Is it possible ?

Comment: How are you _using_ the data? Magento has a specific way of accessing select attribute values from frontend templates using the "frontend" renderer for the attribute's model. If this is what you're doing then you should follow suit. If it's for a data feed or something else/custom logic then continue :D

Comment: @RobbieAverill: thanks for your comment, indeed it is used outside of a frontend instance that is why I'm using pure php library

Answer (score -1):

Please use below code for join product attribute:

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
         ->getCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->addAttributeToFilter('computer_type',array('neq'=>0))
     ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
         ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposition, I may use it the wrong way but is it actually joining with the table containing the attribute value, I only get the 'computer_type' from catalog/product like I already have.